How to print MDC attribute only if log level is ERROR in dropwizard java app
Idea is to print some context only if there is error logs & not on other log levels like info or trace since it is not useful. I tried using log filters but it didnt help.
Reference - https://www.dropwizard.io/en/release-4.0.x/manual/core.html#logging-filters
Sample code -
@JsonTypeName("print-mdc-error-log")
public class PrintMdcErrorLogFilter implements FilterFactory<IAccessEvent> {
    @Override
    public Filter<IAccessEvent> build() {
        return new Filter<IAccessEvent>() {
            @Override
            public FilterReply decide(IAccessEvent event) {
               // modify log event but if we remove mdc then future events will have no mdc
            }
        };
    }
}

